# Authentication when creating Webhooks

Tags: clio-api

Consider this scenario: I have an integration API that communicates with Clio. There are several clients (unique Clio accounts) each with different users that will integrate with the API aka the Clio Application.

I want to use the Clio webhooks but should I create a new webhook for each authorised user or can I have one per client? The Webhook is created using a user's access token and is therefore tied to the access token. However, other users within the same Clio account with authorisation to the same event will trigger all the webhooks?

Can I register 1 wehbook per client or is it per user?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you should use one Clio API token for each Clio client and you should create webhooks on events for each model, not for each user. For example, if you wanted to get a webhook request to your web service for each time a user adds an activity, you would set up the webhook on the activity update event, once. Each time an activity is updated, Clio would make a webhook call to your service for that client. Then each user's interface for that client would check the central repository for that update.